# Populate input form field in a div on button click in React Js

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have to show the input text value that user enters in the input form field below the text box on a button click in reactjs.
I have created the function out of the render function and is returning the value and calling that function on button click but it is not working for me. I am not getting the value on button click which i am writing in textbox on the same page.
Whats the solution for this?

[here i have created the function to set my nput state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6PRh.png)
[here i have to return the state on button click in expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/risjN.png)

Comment: Show us your code...

Comment: It's better if you add your code as actual text, rather than images. Even better would be if you include a jsfiddle or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      values: {},
      showValues: {}
    }
  }

  handleChange(name, e){
    let values = this.state.values;
    values[name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({values: values})
  }

  handleClick(e){
    let inputValues = this.state.values;
    this.setState({showValues: inputValues});
  }

  render(){
    return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.values["one"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "one")}/>
                <p>{this.state.showValues["one"]}</p>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.values["two"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "two")}/>
                <p>{this.state.showValues["two"]}</p>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.values["three"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "three")}/>
                <p>{this.state.showValues["three"]}</p>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.values["four"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "four")}/>
                <p>{this.state.showValues["four"]}</p>

                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Show value</button>
           </div>
    )
  }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Here is updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1185/).

Comment: yes, i want exactly this but let me see if its working for me or not because i have to each value which a user places in textbox on a button click and wants a clickable x as well on the list of names. Clicking on the x will cause the name to be removed .

Comment: The inline list should look something like:

dan x eric x blocktrades x

Comment: can you please help me with that

Comment: I don't understand you very well. Make an jsfiddle with your code, with the exact problem, and then I'll try to help you.

Comment: ok i will try and do that but i just want to hold each and every which i am able to show on button click in <p> tag, thats it nothing else

Comment: ok, i will try and do that but right now i just want to hold each value which i am able show on button click , in <p> tag thats it

Comment: Thanks a lot i got that its working absolutely fine now.

Comment: what i exactly wanted and can you help me with another thing.

Comment: here i have the code in fiddler
http://jsfiddle.net/7zkCU/30/

here, i just want to remove the tag containing the data on clicking of cross button can you help me that pls

Comment: Ask new question with that problem and I'm going to try.