# How to create a functionality to auto populate/fill, text fields on a button click event using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm quiet new to in React Js. Can you please help me to develop a button click functionality which will auto populate/fill given text fields using  pre defined data

Comment: Add the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041484/populate-input-form-field-in-a-div-on-button-click-in-react-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a react class component and render a form. Create a button on click of which it call `setState` and will update the form field values

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class FormComponent extends React.Component {
  autoCompleteValues = {
    userName: ' Test User',
    password: 'password '
  };
  constructor() {
    super();
    // default state of the form fields
    this.state = {
      userName: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }
  autoPopulate = () => {
    // update the state of the form fields
    this.setState({
      userName: this.autoCompleteValues.userName,
      password: this.autoCompleteValues.password
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          value={this.state.userName}
          type="text"
          placeholder="add your name"
        />
        <input
          value={this.state.password}
          type="password"
          placeholder="add password"
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button onClick={this.autoPopulate.bind(this)} type="button">
          Auto Complete
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default FormComponent;
```

Using functional Component

App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FormComponent from './FormComponent';
import FormFunctionalComponent from './FormFunctionalComponent';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const autoFillFunctionalForm = () => {
    setUserName('New user name');
    setPassword('new password');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> With Class component</h1>
      <FormComponent />
      <div>
        <h1> With functional Component </h1>
        <FormFunctionalComponent userName={userName} password={password} />
        <button onClick={autoFillFunctionalForm}>
          Auto Fill functional component form
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Function component

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function FormFunctionalComponent(props) {
  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" value={props.userName} />
      <input type="password" value={props.password} />
    </form>
  );
}
export default FormFunctionalComponent;
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ntg24o)

Comment: Do you know how to do this with functional components. (Not with class components)

Comment: even easier. Create props.I can do it but if you do that will be helpful for you

Comment: Sure I will try, thank you so much BRK.

Comment: brk, Can you please help me on this. I'm quiet struggling with it. I would be glad if you could please do it. So then I can understand the way to do it.

Comment: @Wrthnayaka see the updated ans